# Is It Possible To Run Nodes In Bursts?

Tags: azure, corda

**NOTE:** This question is framed in the context of a *private* network where the business network operator owns and manages *all* the nodes on the network as a service and only provides access via a REST API or a web gui.

Assuming that the application is mostly batch based and not real time, is it possible to run nodes in bursts so that they start once an hour, process any transactions and then shut down again when the processing is complete?

Or maybe have a trigger that starts up the node automatically when it is needed.

Azure has [per second billing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/) which has the potential to drastically reduce infrastructure costs.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this wouldn't be possible. You can think of nodes being like email servers -- You never know when an email (ie a transaction for a Node) comes in, so they have to be online all the time.

However if you control *all* nodes on the network, you could build a queuing system outside of Corda, once an hour spin up all the nodes on the network, and then process your own queue by sending the transactions then.

This would be likely to become tricky once you have other entities you don't control on the network though. You could also run the nodes on the smallest possible instances on Azure and keep the cost down that way?

Comment: The first and third paragraph ignore the context of the question and the middle paragraph isn't doing much more than what is already in the question.

Comment: Ok so let me rephrase my answer: No that isn't something that Corda offers.

You could build your own queuing system, and have it start and stop nodes and issue all the transaction requests manually once they're up though